# Bypass source capacitor JFET

Tags: gain, jfet, bypass-capacitor, formula-derivation

I know there were some changes applied to voltage amplification formula of BJT when "Ce" (emitter bypass capacitor) was connected to the circuit. How is it with JFET (MOSFET too) and its bypass capacitor? I haven't seen any formulas for JFET considering bypass capacitors when equations were discussed. Can anyone suggest how solve this kind of  "problem"? Maybe explain it a bit.

Here is a schematic[image]

Here are some equations (probably refering to different models) for Au:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

*Also from one of my sources (from the one with pink coloured formulas) it says that source bypass capacitor increases gain magnitude!

Comment: Show us the equation for the gain when you are not considering the bypass cap.  Then we will give some recommendations on how to include it.

Comment: @ Keno +1 for thinking .On the face of it things are just like the BJT but input impedance stays high and the gain increase is less when the bypass cap is added .Distortion increases with adding the cap but due to its predominantly 2nd harmonic nature it is less of a problem than with the BJT with its exponential terms .

Comment: @KevinWhite: The edit has been made.

Comment: @Autistic: Check my edit. What do you think of this formulas? Are all approximately same? Or where is the difference between them (except that Rs is applied when the feedback is needed)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gain increases because the capacitor provides small-signal ground (it becomes a short). That is, for the small signal analysis purposes, the capacitor shorts the source resistance to ground making the equivalent resistance at the source zero and the source resistance impacts the final gain.

The formula that you have in pink is the one for a common-source amplifier.

Consider the model of an ideal voltage amplifier as below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0dofe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I went ahead and added the drain and load resistances. And as you probably know, constant potentials (such as Vdd become small signal ground).

Now, what is \$R_{out}\$? It is just the resistance looking into the output of your voltage amplifier, which in this case is the drain. If this was a MOSFET, the resistance looking into the drain when there is a source resistance is

$$ R_{\text{into drain}}=R_{out}=r_o+R_s+\text{gm}r_oR_s $$

You can readily find this in the literature out there. In the voltage amplifier model, \$A\$ is the unloaded voltage gain of a common source, which you can also find online:

$$ A_v=-\text{gm}r_o$$

Now, find an expression for \$\dfrac{v_{out}}{v_{in}}\$, which would be the loaded gain. You have a simple voltage divider:

$$v_{out}=\dfrac{(R_D||R_L)Av_{in}}{(R_D||R_L)+R_{out}} $$

You could now transfer the \$v_{in}\$ on the right hand side, to the left and arrive at:

$$ \dfrac{v_{out}}{v_{in}}=\dfrac{(R_D||R_L)(-\text{gm}r_o)}{(R_D||R_L)+R_{out}}$$

Here is the thing, where \$R_s\$ comes into play. If you didn't have the source capacitor, then \$ R_{out}=r_o+R_s+\text{gm}r_oR_s\$ and your loaded gain equation becomes:

$$ \dfrac{v_{out}}{v_{in}}=-\text{gm}r_o\dfrac{(R_D||R_L)}{(R_D||R_L)+r_o+R_s+\text{gm}r_oR_s}$$

With the capacitor, the equivalent resistance at the source for the small signal model becomes zero since the capacitor shorts \$R_s\$ to ground. Then

\$ R_{out}=r_o+0+\text{gm}r_o(0)=r_o\$

and the loaded gain equation becomes:

$$ \dfrac{v_{out}}{v_{in}}=-\text{gm}r_o\dfrac{(R_D||R_L)}{(R_D||R_L)+r_o}$$

This makes the **denominator smaller**, and therefore theoretical gain increases in comparison with the gain when \$R_s\$ is present.

The equation you have in pink is the same one I have. This could be re-written as

$$ \dfrac{v_{out}}{v_{in}}=-\text{gm}\big(r_o||R_D||R_L\big)$$

They are probably treating the drain the resistance as the total load for the small signal model (\$R_{D,total}=R_D||R_L)\$ for the equations in pink or they simply didn't consider an \$R_L\$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Helped a lot :D